# How does Nodejs and express handle multiple user connections?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, express, server

Let's say I have an expressJs method that instantiates a couple of objects:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
app.get('/api/getInfo/:id', function(req, res) {

    var infoClient = require('./info.js');
    var id = req.param('id');

    var userInfo = new infoClient(id);

    //processes more data
    //does stuff with userInfo etc etc

    res.sends(userInfo);
}
```

How exactly does express or node facilitate multiple getInfo/:id calls? Won't it jumble up the instantiated objects? Does it automatically make each different user connection their own 'instance'?

Comment: For that you should know how HTTP works, you can read [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-the-protocol-every-web-developer-must-know-part-2--net-31155).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Express.js executes the function passed to each route for each request; different user connections each execute the code separately so there is no jumble because the scope of :id is unique for each request.

`app.get('/api/getInfo/:id', function(req, res) { /* code here is executed separately with each request to /api/getInfo/:id */ });`